# How to tune simple sql query with group by

Tags: sql, mysql

I have three tables

1.) Students (id,firstName,Surname,email)

2.) Course_Student(student_id, course_id)

3.) Courses (id, name, classroom_id)

I need to select all students, which have count of curses more or equal  = 3.

I contstruct this select and it seems that it works, but I am curious, if there will be more efective way to this select:

```
select 
  s.firstName, s.Surname 
from 
  students s  
inner join 
  course_student cs 
on 
  s.id = cs.student_id 
and 
  cs.course_id 
in 
  (select 
     course_id 
   from 
     course_student 
   group by 
     course_id 
   having count(*) >= 3
  );
```

Comment: which databse exactly are you using

Comment: I use Mysql database.

Comment: When asking a SQL question, it is necessary to add a tag for the specific RDBMS you're using, as syntax and functionality between them varies. This is explained in the tag description for the SQL tag. We need to know what database you're using, so that someone doesn't take the time to write an answer only to find out that it won't work for your RDBMS. Please [edit]  your post to add that tag.

Comment: Neither your query nor the accepted answer are doing what you wrote ("select all students, which have count of curses more or equal = 3"). What these queries are doing is selecting all students from courses with at least 3 students.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current query selects all students who are on a course which has >= 3 students, but maybe that is what you want.

This query *"select all students, which have count of curses more or equal = 3"*:

```sql
SELECT s.firstName, s.Surname
FROM students s
INNER JOIN course_student cs ON s.id = cs.student_id
GROUP BY s.id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3;
```

Make sure you index your junction table in both directions - `(course_id, student_id)` & `(student_id, course_id)`.

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MqrscCEz).

Answer (score 1):

You can make every `IN` clause into an `INNER JOIN`

```
select 
  s.firstName, s.Surname 
from 
  students s  
inner join 
  course_student cs 
on 
  s.id = cs.student_id 
JOIN   (select 
     course_id 
   from 
     course_student 
   group by 
     course_id 
   having count(*) >= 3
  ) c ON c.course_id =  cs.course_id
```